# Problems understanding simple Batch commands

Tags: batch-file

i do understand that this code puts data from a server into a certain folder called IMS_DUMP_800: it deletes everything inside and then puts the data into it.

What i dont understand is the CD.. and pause afterwards.

Is it so the order is executed well?

Also what is the projectRevision=FS_0G0A3_010_800_23 code part doing?

```
cd IMS_DUMP_800
del *.*
Rem: comand output file name      host/port                    projectbuild unit  
si report --basename=GIF800_0l0 --hostname=ims-es --port=7001--project="/ES/FS/0G/0A3/pis/0l0/project.pj" --projectRevision=FS_0G0A3_0l0_800_23
si report --basename=GIF800_0m0 --hostname=ims-es --port=7001 --project="/ES/FS/0G/0A3/pis/0m0/project.pj" --projectRevision=FS_0G0A3_0m0_800_23
si report --basename=GIF800_0u0 --hostname=ims-es --port=7001 --project="/ES/FS/0G/0A3/pis/0u0/project.pj" --projectRevision=FS_0G0A3_0u0_800_23
si report --basename=GIF800_ec0 --hostname=ims-es --port=7001 --project="/ES/FS/0G/0A3/pis/ec0/project.pj" --projectRevision=FS_0G0A3_ec0_800_23
si report --basename=GIF800_sc0 --hostname=ims-es --port=7001 --project="/ES/FS/0G/0A3/pis/sc0/project.pj" --projectRevision=FS_0G0A3_sc0_800_23
si report --basename=GIF800_ws0 --hostname=ims-es --port=7001 --project="/ES/FS/0G/0A3/pis/ws0/project.pj" --projectRevision=FS_0G0A3_ws0_800_23
si report --basename=GIF800_xc0 --hostname=ims-es --port=7001 --project="/ES/FS/0G/0A3/pis/xc0/project.pj" --projectRevision=FS_0G0A3_xc0_800_23

CD ..

pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CD..` is to reverse the effect of the `CD IMS_DUMP_800` and leave you in the folder you started in.

This can be better achieved with `pushd` and `popd`.

The `PAUSE` is to ensure the user has to take an action to end the script. This permits the user to double-click the script, wait for it to complete, and not have the command-window automatically close when the script ends (permitting them to see any error messages, etc).

As for the last question - I don't know. `si` is not a standard command, so you would need to refer to the documentation for that executable.